# Refreshing async items in flutter dropdown_search package

Tags: flutter

Can async items be loaded using the dropdown_search (https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_search) each time the user enters a new search value?

Edit:
solution is to set:

```
isFilterOnline: true
```